# Is it possible to debug OpenGL shaders with Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have written a shader compiler that compiles the shaders and links the program, but my fragment shader doesn't seem to work. Even though it doesn't give me any error, it compiles and my triangle is still white.

Is there anyway I can debug the shaders?

Here is my fragment shader:

```
#version 330

out vec4 outputColor;
void main()
{
    float lerpValue = gl_FragCoord.y / 500.0f;
    outputColor = mix(vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), vec4(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f),        
                  lerpValue);
}
```

Comment: Use gDebugger.. http://www.gremedy.com/  It lets you debug EVERYTHING.. The calls made, the shaders loaded, the textures, the buffers, etc.. You can literally visually view them all and view the code.. Supports Amd & Nvidia. It's the best I've ever used. Even better than glIntercept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that natively, but you can install [NVIDIA Nsight](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition) to debug your shaders

Comment: Even for Intel igp or Amd cards?

Comment: I believe not, anyway remote debugging might help

Comment: If you have an AMD card, you can use the CodeXL plugin for visual studio.
I can't remember if it works for Intel gpus.